# Setting permissions for certain actions in MTM

Tags: tfs-2015, mtm

Is is possible to associate permissions for certain actions in MTM to predefined groups, so that the MTM UI will only allow the permitted actions to be active, hiding or disabling the unpermitted ones? For example if we have two groups, Testers and Business Analysts, only users from the Testers group can create a new test case. So if we take a look at the image below[image]

the ***New*** button will only be available for Testers and will be disabled for other groups, like afore mentioned Business Analysts for example.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot exactly achieve that, but we can set permissions on the area path for the specific group in TFS to permit or restrict access to edit or modify work items, test cases, or test plans assigned to those areas. It will have the same restriction in MTM.

Please follow below steps to do that.

1. Go to **Area** tab, right click on the area your test plans belong to
   and then click on "**Security**"
2. Grant rights for the specific groups to manage test plans. (eg , In
   you case set **Allow** for **Testers** group and **Deny** for **Business Analysts** group). Of cause you can also set other permissions as needed, eg
   Delete this node, Edit this node etc.

Thus, the users in **Business Analysts** goup can click the **New** button, but cannot save the work item, they will receive the error message ‘***TF237111: The current user does not have permissions to save work items under the specified area path.***’ when save the test case.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch Andy. Did what you said and worked wonderfully.